# sockets not operating in flutter

Tags: flutter, dart, error-handling, socket.io, backend

I am making a flutter app, and I am using socket.io and it doesn't seem to be connecting at all

I am using socket-i*o*-client version  `^2.0.0-beta.4-nullsafety.0`   and socket.io version `3.0.0`

My index.js consists of

```
var server = http.createServer(app);
var io = require("socket.io")(server);
```

and

```
io.on('connection', socket => {
  socket.on("join", (documentId) => {
    socket.join(documentId);
  });
});
```

In the lib folder, the socket_repository consists of

```
class SocketRepository {
  final _socketClient = SocketClient.instance.socket!;

  Socket get socketClient => _socketClient;

  void joinRoom(String documentId) {
    _socketClient.emit('join', documentId);
  }
}
```

My socket_client consists of

```
class SocketClient {
  io.Socket? socket;
  static SocketClient? _instance;

  SocketClient._internal() {
    socket = io.io(host, <String, dynamic>{
      'transports': ['websocket'],
      'autoConnect': false,
    });
    socket!.connect();
  }

  static SocketClient get instance {
    _instance ??= SocketClient._internal();
    return _instance!;
  }
}
```

My document_screen consists of these socket related parts

```
SocketRepository socketRepository = SocketRepository();
```

and

```
socketRepository.joinRoom(widget.id);
```

I was atleast expecting some console output but instead i got nothing!!!